# Login system based on User Accounts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, passwords

I'm still fairly new to Laravel and am trying to wrap my head around using a user account number(or arbitrary unique id) to login instead of email or username.

I have email based login working, but I'm ditching that for this project. Can anyone explain to me what I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5 defaults to email-based login, but you can swap this out by adding a `username` field to your users table* and adding the following line in `app/Http/AuthController.php`:

```
protected $username = 'username';
```

Internally, Laravel checks for a `username` field prior to checking the email field.

[*] You can do this by modifying the `create_users_table` migration located in `database/migrations`. See [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations) docs for how to modify and run database migrations.